# Adding specific post category between posts in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add a specific category of post (such as 'Sponsors') after every 3rd post. Example:

Post Post Post Sponsor
Post Post Post Sponsor
Post Post Post Sponsor

I found this code which is used to inject Adsense between posts in the loop, but is it possible to use this code to add a specific post category between posts in the loop? How would I alter this code to achieve this? Or is there a better method?

Code to inject Adsense between posts:

Add your custom function or introduce your own hook inside the loop:

```
<article id="entry-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('entry group'); ?>>
     <div id="postcontent"></div>
</article>

<?php do_action( 'inject_ads', $wp_query->current_post ); ?>
```

where you can inject your ads like this:

```
add_action( 'inject_ads', function( $i ){

if( 4 === $i % 5 )
{
     echo '... your ad code ...';
}

});
```

code found here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795309/how-to-add-looping-advertisement-and-different-post-stlyes-inside-wp-loop
```

Comment: Hi @leko, did you check out my solution to this question: [How to show Y number of custom posts after every X normal posts?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141596/how-to-show-y-number-of-custom-posts-after-every-x-normal-posts) This is a general solution to the problem and no need to change the theme template. Just include my code as a plugin or in your functions.php file.

Comment: Hi @birgire Thanks for taking the time to reply. I checked out your link. It addresses injecting "custom post types" into the Loop. But can it be used to inject regular posts (except in a specific category)? Also, is there a simpler method to achieve my goal (since I am not using custom post types)? The code seems overkill for my situation, what do you think? I am a beginner with coding so I don't know enough to alter the loop and would appreciate any help.

Comment: ok, let me come back to this in 1 or 2 days, hopefully with a more useful plugin, let's call it *The Sponsor Post Injector* ;-) ... with some custom category setup. cheers

Comment: ps: is this sponsor injection for the main query on the front page?

Comment: Doctor Birgire, _The Sponsor Post Injector_ (haha) sounds like it will be a popular plugin. Yes it is for the main query on the front page.
I rephrased my question more clearly here [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158133/inject-post-from-specific-category-between-posts-in-loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158133/inject-post-from-specific-category-between-posts-in-loop) , and I included info about my Loop (I have a code in functions.php that alters the main query so that I can sort posts by price - will this complicate things? )

Comment: The first plugin draft is available, see your question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158133/inject-post-from-specific-category-between-posts-in-loop).

Answer (score 0):

You better have two WP_Query separately and call the another loop with 'Sponsor' category every 4th post of main loop:

```
$query_with_main = new WP_Query(); // main loop
$query_with_sponsor = new WP_Query('cat_name=sponsor'); // Sponsor loop

    if ( $query_with_main->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query_with_main->have_posts() ) { 
            if ( 0 === $query_with_main->current_post % 4 ) { // To check if 4th of the main loop 
                 if ( $query_with_sponsor->have_posts() ) {
                     $query_with_sponsor->the_post();
                     // Sponsor loop code goes here                           
                 }
            }
            $query_with_main->the_post();
            // Main loop code goes here
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hmm this code did not work. I cannot figure out why. I've rephrased my question here, maybe you can spot a reason why it is not working with my Loop? [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158133/inject-post-from-specific-category-between-posts-in-loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158133/inject-post-from-specific-category-between-posts-in-loop)

Comment: did you change cat_name to your category slug name? it's not category name itself, but slug name.. they're generally same though..